# Empty output in crontab on CentOS

Tags: centos, cron

I wrote a simple script to get IPv4 addresses, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip -4 addr | grep inet | awk -F '[ \t]+|/' '{print $3}' | grep -v ^127.0.0 | tr '\n' ' '
```

It works well when I run it from the bash. Now I created a crontab entry and am hoping to output the ip address to a tmp file:

```
* * * * * /root/ipv4.sh >> /tmp/tmp.txt
```

There is nothing written to `/tmp/tmp.txt`, though the `/tmp/tmp.txt` is touched every minute. It happens only on Cent OS, while on Ubuntu it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by changing `ip` to `/sbin/ip` in the script.